# What is the best way to deal with triggers and events in big forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventtrigger

I have a big form has a lot of tabs and accordions which have a lot of controls Select2, Bootstrap ColorPicker, and some other need a lot of code as well as repeater controls that makes user add/remove new blocks and new items will added to the DOM so i'm using MutationObserver to listen on new added controls and new events, so I'm using a lot of (document.body).on('EVENTS').

Which one is the best way to deal with big form like this...

1. Continue with (document.body).on('') - **Of course there're dozens**

   ```
   $( document.body ).on( 'EVENT', 'ELEMENT', function() {

         // Do Some

   });
   ```
2. Trigger event functions by control's visibility like

   ```
   selector = $( document ).find( 'element:visible' );

   selector.each(function(){

         // Do Some

   });
   ```

Comment: Choose the method that is easiest to read, code, and maintain.

Comment: Yes, event delegation looks like a much better idea than mutation observers, but put them in the form itself rather than the `document.body`.

Comment: Why not just let the repeater set up the events for each repetitive controls box?

Comment: Actually MutationObserver is very easy to trigger something like Select2 or ColorPicker libraries for each new Element specially when you have three nested repeaters but of course the new element's events must trigger individually for each new block or through (document.body) so I'm using the last one

Comment: Probably should stick with .on() if you ask me, much more maintainable, just make sure you are consistent with your coding patter.